# Angular4 app with webpack dev mode suffers from slow performance when using EventEmitters

Tags: typescript, rendering, angular

My Angular 4 application suffers from slow performance when I use @Output event emitters in the dev mode. I try to simplify my setup as much as possible so that the problem is understandable.

A parent component consists of multiple child components. Each child can emit an event via an @Output event emitter.

**parent.component.ts**

```
export class ParentComponent {
  public onSomething() {}
}
```

**parent.template.html**

```
<child *ngFor="let child of children"
     (onSomething)="onSomething($event)"></child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent {
  @Output() onSomething = new EventEmitter(); // type intentionally omitted
}
```

If I navigate to the parent component, Chrome is in  the rendering stage (Timeline tab in the Chrome developer tools) for about 1500ms for the example above. If I remove `(onSomething)="onSomething($event)"`, Chrome is in the rendering stage for about 600ms. If I add multiple onSomethings in the parent template with the corresponding method in the parent class, it gets worse for every additional binding, e.g. 5 bindings result in about 4000ms rendering time.

My setup consists mainly of these components (I'm happy to provide more details, but since I'm not sure what to include, I try to minimize):

- Angular 4 (4.0.0)
- webpack 2.3.2
- webpack-dev-server: 2.4.2

**My questions are:**

- How can I avoid this long rendering time?
- Why does it only occur in dev mode?

**Working live example:**

A working example is commited on https://github.com/mircowidmer/angular2-webpack-starter/commit/ea6511356b13b833f14d455186ec362d7a90c638 and can easily be reproduced.

Comment: Do you have any live example to reproduce it?

Comment: @yurzui: I'm trying to put one together right now.

Comment: I observed that commenting out the line `require('zone.js/dist/long-stack-trace-zone');` in https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/polyfills.browser.ts drastically improves performance in this case.

Comment: I created an issue in the AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter project on Github: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/issues/1654 and added a reproducible example above.